# In an interrupted cricket match, how D/L Method is calculated?

Tags: cricket

We all know that, for making result in cricket match both the umpair goes for the help of D/L method, but how this is been calculated,?  please anybody answer this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this information is well-stated in the official documentartion, and any sufficient answer will necessarily refer to it, or be too long for Stack Exchange.

Comment: I agree the answers are in the official documentation - I think adding a link to that documentation might be helpful, even if the question is closed, so I've done so.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the ICC regulations on Duckworth-Lewis - available as a PDF from [here](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/542b8685a3693-06]%20Duckworth%20Lewis_2014.pdf). There's also a FAQ, although I haven't read it, available from the same site, [here](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/542b84d41b3c2-The%20D_L%20methodology%20-%20Answers%20to%20Frequently%20Asked%20Questions.docx).

Comment: Would be good to add an extract also rather than just having links. If they decide to change the URL then the links will become broken

Comment: That's a fair point, but it's tough to extract a pertinent section when the question is so broad. It really needs the user to read the entire link.